# Unable to get data from localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have faced a hurdle regarding the localstorage get and set.

**Scenario:** I am inserting data from form elements and caching it in an object and this object is pushed inside an array. So every time I am entering data into form elements those data are stored in an object and that object is pushed in an array. After pushing the object in the array `userAry.push(newUser)`.

I have `setItem` the array in localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem('userDataStore',JSON.stringify(userAry))
```

Inside `document.ready` I have

```
$('#getResult').html(localStorage.getItem('userDataStore'))
```

**Problem:**

Inside `document.ready` the `$('#getResult').html(sessionStorage.getItem('userDataStore'))` is not showing the array. Instead it is only showing the recently added data.

If I fill up the form twice consecutively then after page refresh it is showing those 2 data. But if I add another data and refresh the page it should show 3 data instead it is showing the recently added data.

**Code:**

```
var newUser = {
  userName : username,
  userPhno : userphno,
  userEmail : useremail,
  userPass : userpass,
  userConfirmpass : userconfirmpass,
}

userAry.push(newUser);  

localStorage.setItem('userDataStore',JSON.stringify(userAry));
```

Inside `document.ready` I have

```
$('#getResult').html(sessionStorage.getItem('userDataStore'));
```

Comment: Why are you using `localStorage` to set the data, but `sessionStorage` to retreive it?

Comment: Also, adding to @31piy comment, if you are stringifying your json, you need to parse it back and probably loop if you are storing the data in an array

Comment: `localStorage.setItem()` function overwrites your old data with new data. If you want to keep add new values you should use like this -> `localStorage.setItem('key',localStorage.getItem('key')+your_variable)`

Comment: @31piy i copied the wrong statement. A silly mistake from my end.

Comment: @Zaphiel let me try your solution. It seems to be the one.

Answer (score 3):

@NoviceCoder, To work with localstorage you can try below scenerio.

```
response = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
localStorage.setItem("marketPlaceNames", JSON.stringify(response)) // to set value
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("marketPlaceNames")) // to get value
```

Answer (score 0):

in document ready, you should set up variable userAry too. Not only fill the HTML content. then when you push a new item it will add it to the others already created and then when you store the array, you store whole users not only newly added

```
userAry = sessionStorage.getItem('userDataStore');
$("#getResult").html(userAry);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code replace this line `localStorage.setItem('userDataStore',JSON.stringify(userAry));` with `sessionStorage.setItem('userDataStore',JSON.stringify(userAry));`

Check it below code how to get, set and remove data from [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

For example :

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```